# Java How to uniquely identify a Runnable being executed in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I want to find a way to identify a Runnable instance during execution.  Basically I am creating a temporary cache that is accessible by the thread via ThreadLocal, but having it tied to a Thread is not enough as my application is using thread pooling so the same thread will be reused over and over.  Since the Runnable that is passed into the thread will not be reused, I wanted to find a way to get to the Runnable so that I can have a way to identify the same runnable during execution.  It's going to be used as a key to a Map so even just the return from a toString() would be adequate.

I am not creating the thread pool and the threads are created from multiple poolers so I'd rather not try to augment the Thread / Runnable creation process if possible.

I can't seem to find a way to get to anything useful from Thread.currentThread(), but using that would be preferred, if it's possible.

Comment: Can't you use a `ThreadLocal` and clear it when the task completes?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Map` whoes values re the `Runnables` and whose key is its `System.identityHashcode()`. Not perfect, but as good as you will get.

Or else make each `Runnable` have its own `UUID` attribute and use that as a key. Now that's perfect. But more expensive.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. OP wants access to the `Runnable` instance currently executing. Something like `Runnable.currentRunnable()`, if that existed.

Comment: @shmosel No, but evidently I failed to make myself clear.

Comment: @shmosel, yes.  At any arbitrary point, I would like to identify the runnable that is currently being executed.  So if I gave a runnable an id, how would I gain access to that id, or even to the runnable in order to get to the id?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Thread.currentThread()` you can inspect the thread's [stack trace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace--), which will allow you to determine what's running. If you subclass `Runnable` for each task you can easily determine which runnable is executing. Otherwise you can inspect deeper in the stack (i.e. whatever code the runnable is calling) to heuristically determine what is being executed.

Comment: Well it's not very flexible, is it? What if he wants to run more than one instance of a task? and all that mucking around with stack traces and subclasses ...

Comment: I thought of this, but it is a bit kludgy and I wasn't sure just how expensive it would be to pull the stack trace.  This operation will occur a lot, and if it's expensive to pull the stack trace, just to try to get at an id, it would end up defeating the purpose.

Comment: You might consider posting a separate question going into more detail about what you're [actually trying to accomplish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147573); needing to repeatedly inspect a thread's state to see what it's doing (other than for debugging) is highly unusual and doesn't seem like the right approach. Without knowing more about the underlying goal it's difficult to offer better options, however.